# Python Selenium seleniumrequests GET with Proxy executing twice?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

```
from seleniumrequests import Chrome
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://192.168.1.115:80')

baseURL = "https://www.iplocation.net/"

try:
    with Chrome(options=options) as wd:
        result = wd.request('GET', baseURL)
        with open("result.txt", "w") as page:
            page.write(result.txt)
except:
    print("fail")
```

Running this code, the Chrome instance that opens correctly displays the page with my proxy ip address in the result.

The result.txt file, however, contains the full identical page text, except the ip address is my actual external ip address, not the proxy address.

If I use an invalid Proxy address, the Chrome page fails to connect and I still get a valid result.txt with my ip address.

I'm not sure how that is even possible? I mean, other than I don't really know what I'm doing.

The reason I'm using seleniumrequests is that ultimately I will be using a POST. Post or Get in this code returns the same results.

Thanks for any thoughts...

Comment: You're sending the request in your native code.  That has nothing to do with the webdriver.

Comment: So when you use driver.get() the browser is going to make the GET call to the site.  Similarly when you click to submit a form the browser will send the POST.  Your options settings are applied to the browser.  When you make the GET or POST yourself you're not going through the browser so those browser options won't apply.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I think I understand what you're suggesting, but I'm not using a driver.get explicitly. That one request('GET') is all I'm doing, giving 2 different results simultaneously. When that line executes, the browser page opens and displays the proxy ip, which makes sense since the options are being applied to the browser as you said. At the same time, the text file is written from the result and shows a different ip, after just that one operation. So is it performing 2 GETs every time?

Comment: not familiar with "seleniumrequests"... that's doing something sorta odd.  It's adding a way to do two requests at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work in a way I don't need. I will take a different approach. Really appreciate the replies.